# Symfony 2 - disable translations on certain paths/routes

Tags: symfony, translation, symfony-2.8

I would like to disable translations or force using english ones for paths which starts with `/admin`.

Is there a way to approach it in config?

If not what would be the best practice? `EventListener` checking routes and forcing english translation no matter the locale set in request?

Comment: Now maybe its just me, but just don't make it translatable it in the first place? Or just remove any translation and have the English as default fallback.

Comment: I want it not to be translated only in certain routes, in others page is translated

Comment: Yes but before something is translated you have to define it as being translatable, just don't. But id assume your using lots of bundles then no?

Comment: Yes I am using certain bundles that have translations that are not mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you [import your routes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/external_resources.html) you can also set the default locale on it and no other options to set it (example routing.yml):

```
app:
  resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
  type: annotation

app.admin:
  resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/Admin/'
  type: annotation
  prefix: /admin
  defaults:
      _locale: nl
```

Comment: Looks clean, I will try it and tell you if it helps.

Comment: It is set as default, what happens if I set locale in url? Default will be changed?

Comment: There is no option to set it in the url as it wont match, see other answer for that variant however its required to only allow nl there too, both do the same. Only his allows nl/admin too.

Comment: Okay thanks, I like your answer clean and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `EventListener` approach is the most comfortable: http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html

Set the locale within `Request` object. Hint: you can check a route name using `_route` attribute instead of checking an absolute URL.

Answer (score 0):

taken from [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/translation/locale.html#the-locale-and-the-url):

```
app.admin:
  resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/Admin/'
  type: annotation
  prefix: /{_locale}/admin
  requirements:
      _locale: nl
```

put the locale in the url, this is much more search engine friendly.  As the docs say:

> A better policy is to include the locale in the URL. This is fully-supported by the routing system using the special _locale parameter:

Comment: On the quote: I feel this would be a better policy _if_ he actually wanted various locale options, but hes trying the opposite.